# AngularJS $apply with scope var raises exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetimepicker

I am trying to do a very basic example. A datetimepicker with a binding to a simple text.

**html**

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl as ctrl">
        <p><h1>{{ctrl.text}}</h1></p>
        <p>-----------------------------</p>
        <input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
        <p>{{ctrl.result}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**js**

```
var testController = angular.module('testApp.testModule', []);

testController.controller('testCtrl', [function () {
    var myScope = this;
    myScope.text = '#### Controls binding test ####';

    jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
            myScope.$apply(function () {
                myScope.result = $input.val();
            });
        }
    });
}]);
```

When I run the following exception is raised:
[image]

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

I am using the alternative 'new' control naming using a var scope instead of $scope, and tried to just replace $scope with myScope, but with no success.

AngularJS v1.2.24
jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.2.5
jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.1

Comment: If you want to make use of methods of $scope, you need to inject it. This, is just a plain JS function. it does not inherit from scope. (it is placed on/into the scope, but that's not relevant to your question)

Comment: How can I inject the $scope into the myScope object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the job

```
var testController = angular.module('testApp.testModule', []);

testController.controller('testCtrl', [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
    this.text = '#### Controls binding test ####';
    var vm = this; //viewModel
    jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                vm.result = $input.val();
            });
        }
    });
}]);
```